# flash as1: class creation - static functions - possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-1

Can i create static function in a class in action script 1 ?
please provide an example.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a global function in case of AS1 projects

```
_global.myFunction = new function(param1, param2)
{
  // do stuff
  trace("1: " + param1 + "\n 2:" + param2 );
}
```

Call it like this

```
_global.myfunction("hello", 42);
```